# VS Code call stack rows in Flutter App developing

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

While I'm developing the flutter app in debug mode, when I launch the app for the first time, two row added to the call stack as "main" and every time I restart the app, one or two row added in the call stack as "_spawn" and "main".
[image]
What does it mean? Does it mean that a new thread added? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: These rows represent threads/isolates. It sounds like a bug if they're building up - please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code!

Comment: Same issue here, the main threads keep duplicating on every reload. Did you ever had sorted this out?